# New version of vmc gives error: CFoundry::TargetRefused: target refused connection (getaddrinfo: No such host is known. )

Tags: cloud-foundry

From my corporate network I tried using the following versions of vmc: 0.5.0.beta.7 and 0.4.7. When I try doing **vmc target api.cloudfoundry.com**, I get the following error:

```
CFoundry::TargetRefused: target refused connection (getaddrinfo: No such host is known. )
```

When I tried version 0.3.18, I did not get that error. Note that I have set the http proxy correct by setting http_proxy environmental variable.

Did anybody experience this issue or know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

To get VMC to work behind a corporate firewall (SOCKS), you can use socksify (http://socksify.rubyforge.org/). I just added the following (corrected for my environment) to gems/vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:

```
require 'socksify'
TCPSocket::socks_server = "127.0.0.1"
TCPSocket::socks_port = 9050
```

Not exactly elegant, but it worked well and I can finally use CF.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try doing vmc target on a network which doesn't require any proxy settings?